# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel9, trying to seperate frontend and backend. I did many replace, like app\Http change to be app\Frontend\Http or app\Backend\Http.

I did the separation before, it worked. Now I cannot login or logout. But welcome page is ok. Maybe this is because the routes file ?

```
Auth::routes();
```

All content of routes/web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::group( 
    [ 
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ], 
    ], function() 
{ 
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', [App\Frontend\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

I also did:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

not working.

LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Frontend\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Frontend\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Frontend\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
...
```

Comment: Try to wrap `Auth::routes()` in a group with custom namespace like `Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Frontend\Http\Controllers'], function () {Auth::routes();});` does this helps?

Comment: Amazing!! You saved my day! You can post as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth routes of `laravel/ui` package is kinda hardcoded within `AuthRouteMethods` class. This is the [part](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php#L16) of its method from Github repository

```php
$namespace = class_exists($this->prependGroupNamespace('Auth\LoginController')) ? null : 'App\Http\Controllers';
$this->group(['namespace' => $namespace], function() use($options) {
     // Login Routes...
     if ($options['login'] ?? true) {
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
     } 

// more code
```

It ensure that Auth routes will be under "default" namespace of `Theme\Http\Controllers`. But you may change it if wrap it in a group like

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Frontend\Http\Controllers'], function () {
  Auth::routes();
});
```

This way you'll prepend group namespace to it so package will find `App\Frontend\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` class and so on for every other auth controller

**Note 1** - all controllers should be under `Auth` namespace and named specifically as defined in a package, you cannot change it to be like `App\Whatever\LoginController` or `Auth\Whatever\Auth\MyLoginController` - but you can do it with `App\Whatever\Auth\LoginController`

**Note 2** - this wouldn't work with uncommented `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` property within `RouteServiceProvider` class, as it will prepend namespace twice (you will get something like `App\Http\Controllers\App\Frontend\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`)